# How can I generate a PHP array and then insert it into a PHP file?

Tags: php, arrays, bash, metaprogramming, directory-structure

I want to dynamically build a directory tree of my web application in PHP at build time and insert it into a PHP file. It would an n-dimensional array consisting of every file in my web root. I need to format this as a PHP file to then include in my web application.

Comment: you can list that with php itself

Comment: I don't care if it's generated using a PHP script or Bash, but I don't want it looping over my directory structure and populating the array at runtime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[var_export](http://www.php.net/var_export) is what you are looking for.

> var_export() gets structured information about the given variable. It is similar to var_dump() with one exception: the returned representation is valid PHP code.

```
<?php
  file_put_contents( $myFile, var_export( $myArray, $return = true  ) );
?>
```

Comment: Doh! I looked into `var_dump` and `print_r`; I can't believe I missed `var_export`.

Comment: I did the same before discovering var_export.  It doesn't have many uses, but invaluable for the uses it does have.

Comment: +1 good point, but ` file_put_contents( $myFile, var_export( $myArray ) );` not working , it just prints the `var_export` 's output to screen

Comment: Needed to include $return = true in var_export.  It should work as expected now.